# How to get count of specific array item

Tags: php

I stored product in an array and now I have set a limit on order like for product id 49 these should be only 3 orders website should accept for this purpose I need product count.

```
order id           Product Id
  od1           [49 ,50 ,51 ,52 ,]
  od2           [48 ,49 ,50 ,51 ,]
  od3           [49 ,50 ,51 ,52 ,54 ,]
  od4           [51 ,52 ,54 ,55 ,56 ,]
```

I am using core PHP.
I need an overall product count of like 52:- Output should be 3

Comment: Loop through the orders array, and use `in_array()` to test if the product ID is in the product ID array. If it is, add 1 to the counter variable.

Comment: You should add a column to your products table like "max_usages" etc and increase that counter after every order and check if max_usage reaches for that product before new order creation. If you want to stick with current approach, better iterate over all orders and increase counter by searching arrays